# PyTorch to ONNX conversion problem - torch.randn

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx

Using [this](https://github.com/rosinality/stylegan2-pytorch) reimplementation of StyleGAN in PyTorch, I am trying to export the generator as an `.onnx` file using the following code:

```
import model
import torch

Gen = model.StyledGenerator(512)
dummy_input = torch.randn(1,512)
model1 = Gen

torch.onnx.export(model1, dummy_input, "disc.onnx", verbose=True)
```

When I run the script, I got a type error (see below) due to the translation of `torch.randn`. Do you have suggestions on how to fix this?

```
TypeError: i_(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: torch._C.Node, arg0: str, arg1: int) -> torch._C.Node

Invoked with: %227 : Tensor = onnx::RandomNormal(), scope: StyledGenerator
, 'shape', 222 defined in (%222 : int[] = prim::ListConstruct(%218, %219, %220, %221), scope: StyledGenerator
) (occurred when translating randn)
```

To duplicate the problem, you need to download/clone the github repo and cd to that folder.

Comment: You could make the additional random tensor a second input to the network instead of generating a random tensor during the forward pass. This would require editing the pytorch code to take a second tensor as input.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that the size of the second noise tensor changes as we move in the generator architecture, so there isn't an easy way to implement your suggestion. Another option could be to build the random vector using another function.